# dynamic charge sharing between multiple gates

Tags: cmos, vlsi

Based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN4oIcAPIV4 
hopefully it is legitimate [image]

I understand what is being done here. However, I don't understand it well enough for a more complex case such as this[image]

lets say I want to find the reduction of voltage at this node

[image]

adding in capacitors

[image]

Is it correct to say that

worst case here is ABC=110

C2 and C3 will appear in series, so let Cs= 1/(1/C2 +  1/C3 )

and CL VDD + C1 V1 +Cs V2 = ( CL + C1 + Cs ) VOH

Answer (score 0):

The worst case happens for ABCD=1100. Also C2 and C3 are in parallel not series, so Cs=C2+C3. However, the equation you derived is still right.